# Selenium: Part of text present

Tags: selenium

Is there a way to verify only part of text present?

If there is a text "Warning: A15P09 has not been activated." I need to verify the text is present. However, 'A15P09' is not always the same, so I cannot do something like

```
Selenium.IsTextPresent("Warning: A15P09 has not been activated.");
```

I might do something like:

```
Selenium.IsTextPresent("has not been activated.");
```

But is there another way to verify this in Selenium. Please let me know if there is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `getText` and then do any normal regex that your language supplies for examining that result.

**Edit:** And for some languages you can do `isTextPresent` on a pattern modified string.  The documentation states:

> Various Pattern syntaxes are available
> for matching string values:
>
> glob:pattern: Match a string against a
> "glob" (aka "wildmat") pattern. "Glob"
> is a kind of limited
> regular-expression syntax typically
> used in command-line shells. In a glob
> pattern, "*" represents any sequence
> of characters, and "?" represents any
> single character. Glob patterns match
> against the entire string.
>
> regexp:regexp: Match a string using a
> regular-expression. The full power of
> JavaScript regular-expressions is
> available.
>
> exact:string: Match a
> string exactly, verbatim, without any
> of that fancy wildcard stuff.
>
> If no
> pattern prefix is specified, Selenium
> assumes that it's a "glob" pattern.

Comment: @ borrible: so would Selenium.IsTextPresent("glob: Warning: * has not been activated."); work?